# How to find the origin of OSX Fuse installed on my system? Then remove it

Tags: macos, mac, filesystems, macfuse

I have a computer running OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.4. Recently (within the last month) I noticed OSX Fuse in my System Preferences pane. However, I did not install OSX Fuse to my knowledge. In fact, I use Fuse4x through Homebrew, which is the reason I discovered that OSX Fuse was there (throws errors when running `brew doctor`). Previously, on another machine I had used OSX Fuse (when I used MacPorts), but this has never been the case on the current machine.

Seeing that was rather suspicious, so I decided to remove OSX Fuse from my machine. I have since found OSX Fuse to persist and it's becoming rather aggravating. Whether I deliberately remove the OSX Fuse materials from `/usr/local` or I use the `remove` button in the preferences-pane, the files will come back everytime I restart the machine. Is it possible that some software on this machine needs these files? How would I find the source of the installation? Alternatively, is there a possibility that the machine has been compromised by a third parter who wants file-system access to my machine?

I would love to get rid of this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some snooping and found that **SugarSync** secretly installs OSX Fuse *every time* it launches. That was causing OSX Fuse to return during startup. Considering that OSX Fuse is not yet compatible with homebrew, I will unfortunately have to get rid of SugarSync for the time being.

SugarSync should warn the user when it has to install third party software into my `/usr/local` folder. I would have liked it to be more up front about this instead of trying to take away my ability to control the behaviour. Had it been able to use Fuse4x that is already installed, I would have been able to continue using it on this machine.